# Key-Value observing not working IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, addobserver

Hi I am developing IOS application in which I am using add observer with key value pair. But it's not working. I did following things:

```
[self.scrollView addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"new"
                     options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                     context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    // inside here ... 
}
```

But its not calling the above method. If I change `forKeyPath` to `contentOffset` then its working fine. But I want to change that value. Am I doing something wrong? Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: what is "new"? I don't think it's a property of UIScrollView

Comment: Can you please share a little more info on what are you trying to observe? Because `new` isn't a property of `UIScrollView` (and that's why the method isn't called)...

Comment: I want to apply different property for my scrollview rather than content offset but it is not working.

Comment: Like Stavash mentioned you can not observer a value that is not part of the key for ScrollView. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729134/how-do-i-properly-observe-the-contentoffset-property-of-my-scrollview-subclass

Answer (score 1):

`[webView.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`

You need to give the property of the scrollview here.

Comment: yeah this thing is working for me. Can we apply any other property of scrollview.